# Problem with trigger, it compiles fine, but when trying to trigger it gives error

Tags: plsql, triggers

After setting trigger :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Data_modyfikacji
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON Pracownik
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN  
:NEW.DataModyfikacji := sysdate;
 
IF :NEW.Pensja!= :OLD.Pensja THEN
UPDATE Pracownik
SET PoprzedniaPensa = :OLD.Pensja;
END IF;
end;
```

It compiles without errors.
But when i try to trigger it and update info in Pracownik Table like this :

```
Update Pracownik
Set Pensja = 2600 
Where IDPracownik = 3
```

Im getting this error :

```
ORA-04091: table S90323.PRACOWNIK is mutating, trigger/function may not see 
it
ORA-06512: at "S90323.DATA_MODYFIKACJI", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'S90323.DATA_MODYFIKACJI'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the mutating table error because your trigger is updating the same table that the trigger is based on, which you're not allowed to do in Oracle (you'd be retriggering the trigger, potentially multiple (or infinite) times). You also don't have a predicate in your update statement, so you'd be updating all rows in the table, which seems illogical.

What I suspect you're trying to do is set the `poprzedniapensa` value for the row you're updating. If so, you should just set the value in the :new record:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER data_modyfikacji
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON pracownik
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.datamodyfikacji := SYSDATE;

  IF :new.pensja != :old.pensja
  THEN
    :new.poprzedniapensa = :old.pensja;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

If your `pensja` column could be null, you might need to check for nulls in your `IF` statement as well, as your `:new.pensja != :old.pensja` check won't return true if one is null and the other not null.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem.

Comment: Why run this trigger on Delete? It sets a modified date and checks for change in the column pensja. The trigger will fire, do all of its processing and then throw it away. There is no need setting a column the row will NOT show up afterward.

Comment: @Belayer excellent point! Edited my answer to reflect your point.